# Apache: Rewrite domain path bug when .htaccess used in non-root dir

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path, dns

How to fix rewrite rule, so that it works also trough domain.com/path/.htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If rule used in domain.com/.htaccess, redirecting works fine:

```
www.domain.com/path/url -> domain.com/path/url
```

If rule used in domain.com/path/.htaccess, redirected **incorrect**:

```
www.domain.com/path/url -> domain.com/url // Why not domain.com/path/url ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` provides you the full path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```